# How to pass session variables via security context

Tags: spring

I'm working in MVC application. I need to put/pass couple of values in the controller level and retrieve the same in the service or business layer or persistence layer.

Few said we need to defined security context which is accessible in presentation or in any layer.

Please let me know how to define and access it. Is there is a better way then security context?

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend to pass such data as parameter to service layer or persistence layer. If there are many parameters, you can pass the object that holds the paramater values, may be in POJO style.

Comment: What are those values? Where do they come from? What are they used for?

Comment: userId, userName, tenantId, tenantName - four attributes needed. passing as parameter is high maintenance and painful for all methods which is invoking service layer

Comment: If you want to go with `SecurityContextHolder` this post http://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security may help you in using it.

Comment: Kamal, i saw how they are retrieving the value in the above link. However setting the variable in security context is not clear. can u pls help me with a code snippet or the exact line

Comment: You don't need to tie anything of that to Spring security. Just use a session-scoped (or request-scoped) spring bean to store those 4 values, and inject it wherever you need them.

Comment: How to access session scoped bean in business layer. any example or link would be useful

Comment: As far as i know you should not access the session scoped bean in business layer as session scoped bean is for presentation layer